# How to write a custom made dataset in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset(named myresearch.txt) of research of my lab,can i installed in  package:datasets?
1.How can i see it when to use command

```
data()
```

2.How can i load it when to use command

```
attach(myresearch)
```

Comment: I want it included as my actual datasets package named myresearch,which i can call it with attach(myresearch)  as attach(mtcars).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you're asking whether you can add datasets to the "datasets" package that is installed with R.

For that, I would say the answer is "No", "Not likely", or "This is probably not the right forum to get an answer to that question". Or, it is a follow-up question like "Is it an awesome enough and flexible enough dataset that the R Core team will want to include it in future R versions?"

If you just want the *functionality* of being able to flexibly load your datasets in an R session, you can create your own R package that includes your data. See, in particular, ***Section 1.1.5: Data in packages*** from the "[Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.pdf)" manual.

For this, the best thing would be to load your data via the standard methods and save it to an .RData or an .rda file in your package's "data" directory. You should read up on *lazy-loading* in particular, if you are looking for different ways to easily make the data from the package available.

---

If this is purely for personal use, though, I don't know why you wouldn't just save your dataset or datasets as an .RData file and just add something like `load("myData.RData")` to the top of your script to make the data available.

Comment: That's indeed a long "no". :)